# ASP.NET Input type image...how to make it link to page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

How do I make an input button with the type of image, link to another page.  Asp.net JavaScript...etc...

`<input type="image" src="blah blah" onclick="">`

How do I make it link onclick?

Comment: Have you tried `ImageButton`?

Comment: I showed what I have in post (after edit).

Comment: That's not even an ASP.net control, it's just html that is sent to the Browser without ASP.net doing anything with it. Try this: `<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="[id here]" ImageUrl="[url here]" OnClick="[name of onclick handler here]" />`

Answer (score 1):

Four options

**The non javascript way.**

```
<form method="get" action="mypage.aspx">
   <input type="image" src="blah blah">
</form>
```

**The inline javascript way**

```
<input type="image" src="yourImage.gif" onclick="window.location.href = 'mypage.aspx';">
```

**The jQuery way**

```
<input type="image" src="yourImage.gif" data-target="mypage.aspx">
<script>
  $('input[type=image]').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); window.location.href = $(this).data('target'); })
</script>
```

**The non button way**

```
<a href="mypage.aspx" style="border:none"><img src="myimage"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<input type="image" src="yourImage.gif"
    onclick="window.location.href = 'anotherPage.aspx';">
```